# CodeIgniter Localhost redirecting to xampp homescreen

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, url-rewriting

When I run CI project in the browser, using **localhost/hr**, it redirects me to **localhost/dashboard/**.

Searched different solutions but didn't get it working. here is my .htaccess file in "**htdocs/hr**" folder

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Note: There is no **.htaccess** file in **htdocs** folder.

When i remove/rename index.php file and access to **htdocs** it gives me error.

```
Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
```

What am i doing wrong, how to get it working?

Screenshot of my **htdocs/hr** folder is bellow

[image]

Comment: what is there in your route.php

Comment: `$route['default_controller'] = "site";
$route['404_override'] = '';`

Comment: after `RewriteEngine On` put `RewriteBase /hr/`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to set `RewriteBase` in your `.htaccess` file in your folder, which is in your case `ci`.

So you would currently have

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
```

You should change it to

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /ci/
```

And that's it. It will work now.

Comment: Really Appreciate Man :)

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Comment: @NomanAli you should accept this answer if it solves your problem, this will help future visitors.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [`RewriteBase` directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase) and then try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /hr/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Plus, you need to make sure that Apache's rewrite module is enabled:

```
# Check if it's enabled:
apachectl -M | grep rewrite

# You might need sudo here:
a2enmod rewrite

# On platforms that a2enmod is not available, you need 
# to open up your httpd.conf file and uncomment the line
# that looks like this:
LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/mod_rewrite.so
```